# JSON object pass to controller for using it in nested set model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, json.net

I am making a tree structure with the help of JQuery and Javascript.

The tree has the HTML structure of `<ul><li>..` and within
every `li` there is a `div` that contains two spans.

The first span contains an image and the latter contains the node data.

When the tree is completed I have to pass 
the complete tree as a JSON object to a controller
to use it for assigning the left right values using nested set model.

How can I make the JSON object?

Comment: do you need a sample code for

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to your `<ul>`:

```
<ul id='tree'>
    <li><div><span><img src='...' /></span><span>data</span></div></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And then use `stringify` from the `JSON` object to get the JSON string:

```
$(function() {
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify($("#tree")[0]);
});
```

If you've got JQuery referenced properly, then that should give your the JSON representation of your tree.